# Bipartite Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I know that graph G is bipartite iff G does not contain any odd cycle.
Does it mean that G is not bipartite iff G contains any odd cycle ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a question of graph theory, but more of logic. Let $P$ be the statement "$G$ is bipartite" and $Q$ be the statement "$G$ does not contain an odd cycle".

If $P\rightarrow Q$, then we know that $Q^c\rightarrow P^c$ (not $Q$ implies not $P$). You can read about it [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

You also have $Q\rightarrow P$, so $P^c\rightarrow Q^c$.

Hence, $P^c$ if and only if $Q^c$.

What does $P^c$ mean? It means "$G$ is not bipartite", and $Q^c$ means "$G$ contains some odd cycle".

Comment: It shall be noted that this only works in classical logic

Answer (score 1):

We have two statements $A: G \text{ is bipartite}$ and $B: G \text{  contains an odd cycle}$. We have by hypothesis that

$$A \Longleftrightarrow \neg B$$
Where $\neg$ represents logical negation. 
This is equivalent to the two statements
$$A\implies \neg B\\
\neg B \implies A$$

We know that the contrapositive of a statement is logically equivalent to it, so we take the contrapositive of the two given statements and get
$$B \implies \neg A\\
\neg A \implies B$$

Combining these together just as we separated the first two, we have 
$$\neg A \Longleftrightarrow B $$ Which is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is yes. This is an essential graph theoretic proof, and your question/statement follows directly as being true by contrapositive as Daniel Montealegre dutifully described. I should mention that this is a bidirectional implication, and so the iff follows on your new question/statement as well, exactly as you have stated.